# ElevateZoom with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm an absolute novice at coding, so please forgive any mistakes in advance.

I have a very simple, hand-coded store with 3 products:

1. White T Shirt [default selection]
2. Grey T Shirt
3. Navy Striped T Shirt

The user can see a preview of each T Shirt using radio buttons, which changes the image src with a Javascript.

I'm then trying to use ElevateZoom Jquery plugin (http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples) to allow the user to zoom in on the chosen preview image, which uses the same image src file as the zoomed image.

So far, I have the code working well *as long as* the user has clicked on one of the radio buttons. However, ElevateZoom will not run until a radio button has been clicked - therefore the default image (White T Shirt) will not zoom unless the user selects another radio button first, then chooses "White T Shirt" radio button again.

Here's the relevant Javascript/Jquery:

```
            function chooseTee() {
            var image_src;

            if (document.getElementById('whiteTee').checked) {
                image_src = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lovealetter/white-t-shirt.jpg";

            }else if (document.getElementById('greyTee').checked) {
                image_src = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lovealetter/grey-t-shirt.jpg";
            }else{
                image_src = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lovealetter/navy-t-shirt.jpg";
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tee').attr('src', image_src);
            $('#tee').data('zoom-image', image_src).elevateZoom({ 
            zoomType: "inner", 
            cursor: "crosshair",
            responsive: "True",
            });
        });
    }
```

and the relevant HTML:

```
    <div class="img">
    <img id="tee" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lovealetter/white-t-shirt.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/lovealetter/white-t-shirt.jpg" />
    <div class="colourpicker">
    Available colours:<br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="white" id="whiteTee" onclick="javascript:chooseTee();" checked />White
    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="grey" id="greyTee" onclick="javascript:chooseTee();" />Grey
    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="navy" id="navyTee" onclick="javascript:chooseTee();" />Navy
    </div>
    </div>
```

Would be very grateful to hear of simpler ways to do this or indeed a fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see `#tee` and why is `$(document).ready(function() {` inside `chooseTee`? lose it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xPL1LS?p=preview)

The key to getting this before you click a radio button is to add code that executes right after the page has loaded like this:

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tee").elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
    cursor: "crosshair",
    responsive: "True",
  });
});
```

It looks like you had some similar code inside a function that was not called when the page loaded. Also, you do not need to include `data('zoom-image', image_src)` on page load because that information is included in the HTML.

For the zoom to work correctly while using the same src you'll need to change the `img` width with CSS to be smaller than the actual image's width.

### CSS

```
#tee {
  width: 400px;
}
```

After looking at the [ElevateZoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) documentation, it looks like it was intended to be used with two separate image files. You would put the smaller version as your `src` and the zoomed-in version in `data-zoom-image`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!